# Change the description of the 'curiosity' badges

Tags: feature-request

The Curious, Inqusitive and Socratic badges have descriptions of the form:

> Asked a good question on {n} separate days, and maintains a positive question record.

However, the "Good Question" badge is defined as:

> Question score of 25 or more

I have an Inquisitive badge, but no Good Question badges... so we clearly have a difference in definition.

My guess is that 'good question' is not the same a 'Good Question'. Can we change the badge descriptions of the curiosity badges to be a little more descriptive about what a 'good question' is?